# how to get a c# method to run on a timer?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get a C# method to run on a timer?  I found this example online but the DoStuffOnTimer() method below is not getting hit:

```
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var intervalMs = 5000;
        var timer = new Timer(intervalMs);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoStuffOnTimer);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void DoStuffOnTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: You need to call `Start` on the timer. [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Start` just sets `Enabled` to true @bu

Comment: whict timer are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White Seems like `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: yes I'm using System.Timers.Timer within a console app

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't need very precise timer you always can create it yourself:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Temp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        // this is the `Timer`
        private static async Task CallWithInterval(Action action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(interval, token);
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                action();
            }
        }

        // your method which is called with some interval
        private static void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ding!");
        }

        // usage sample
        private static void Main()
        {
            // we need it to add the ability to stop timer on demand at any time
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // start Timer
            var task = CallWithInterval(DoSomething, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cts.Token);

            // continue doing another things - I stubbed it with Sleep
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            // if you need to stop timer, let's try it!
            cts.Cancel();

            // check out, it really stopped!
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program thisone = new Program();
            thisone.DoStuff();
            Console.Read();
        }

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            var intervalMs = 5000;
            Timer timer = new Timer(intervalMs);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoStuffOnTimer);
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void DoStuffOnTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do stuff
            Console.WriteLine("Tick!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tick() isn't available on System.Timers.Timer

Comment: try static var and class method instead of new eventhandler, and reference this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks george.  I copied the code from the url you provided into a new console app and it works.  so there must be something else weird with my program that I need to debug

Comment: I think it could be the var - time. Your time var is a local var, the garbage collection may think it needs be freed. So, the time is freed before it runs.